# How to scroll down to a specific index of a list contained in a Scrollview ? (Nativescript-vue)

Tags: javascript, scrollview, nativescript, nativescript-telerik-ui, nativescript-vue

I'm writing a mobile application using `nativescript-vue`.

I have a list contained in a Scrollview (which is contained in a Tabview).
When my app goes to this tab, I want the Scrollview to scroll down to a specific index of the list that is contained.

I tried this :

```
<ScrollView id="ScrollView" @loaded="onLoaded">
    <ListView for="item in items" class="list-group">
     ...

onLoaded() {         
this.$refs.page.nativeView.getViewById("ScrollView").scrollToVerticalOffset(200, false);
}
```

This does not work, whatever the value for the offset parameter.

Do I miss something?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a mistake to wrap ListView within ScrollView as ListView itself is scrollable. You may use [scrollToIndex](https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/nativescript-ui/api/classes/radlistview.html#scrolltoindex) on RadListView to scroll down / up to specific index.

```
// Scrolls to 50th index
listView.scrollToIndex(50);
```

Also make sure your items are populated on UI before you call this method. I think you should use [dataPopulatedEvent](https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/nativescript-ui/api/classes/radlistview.html#datapopulatedevent) for that.

Comment: It was so simple ...
Thank you very much Manoj !